error in django 404 Page not found (404) Request Method: GET
When clicking on this link: http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/register it gives a 404 error, I do not know what to do with it
Here is the code:
registration/urls.py:
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('/register', views.register, name='register'),
]

registration/views.py:
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import RegistrationForm
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect


def sign_up(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            form = RegistrationForm()
            return render(request, 'registration/register.html', {'form': form})


def register():
    print("hello!")

urls.py(In the project itself):
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('main.urls')),
    path('news/', include('news.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

I've tried a lot of YouTube videos and documentations, but everything is even

The main urls.py file includes main/urls.py and news/urls.py, but not registration/views.py.

You're talking about:from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.urls import path
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', include('main.urls')),
path('news/', include('news.urls')),
path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) ?

The url you are trying to access is defined in registration/urls.py.  But the main urls.py  file does not refer to it.

On your urls.py if you put the
urlpatterns = [
    path('/register', views.register, name='register'), ]

and use something like
urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'), ] 

I think that's the error, you only need to change the bar from /register to 'register/'
